# Python doesn't see installed module entity.rfc3413.oneliner

Tags: python, pysnmp

thank you in advance for help.

Here is an issue, I use module pysnmp with pyasn1, I am using this example:
http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html , and getting an error:

```
# python snmp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "snmp.py", line 1, in <module>
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
File "/home/user_name/rrd_poller/pysnmp.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: No module named **entity.rfc3413.oneliner**
```

Other question is why it refers to **entity.rfc3413.oneliner** but not to **pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner** . Also, I checked

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/entity/rfc3413/oneliner/__init__.py
```

These server has two versions of python installed one is in /usr/bin/ other in /opt, When I do:

```
which python
```

I get:

```
/opt/python/python/Python-2.7.5/python # which is correct location
```

Modules are installed:

```
#python -c "help ('modules')"
```

Gives:

```
pysnmp and pyasn1
```

Comment: I made a `virtualenv` and then ran `easy_install pycrypto` and `easy_install pysnmp` then ran the referenced example in tutorial. It works.

Comment: Is the file `pysnmp.py` mentioned in the traceback a script you have written as opposed to part of the pysnmp installation?  If so, does it help if you rename it to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Python tries to resolve your module (pysnmp.py) as top-level pysnmp package component so it can't get past it to reach 'entity' sub-package which is absent in *your* module. That's why renaming your script to a non-conflicting name might help.

Answer (score 0):

## Use pysnmp

```
pip install -U pysnmp

[root@localhost]# python
Python 2.7.5 

    >> from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
    >>
```